# building a responsive site with absolute positioning

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, absolute

So I'm trying to build this page without using tables but it's proving to be quite difficult getting everything to be lined up and stay in one place, all while being able to be resized based on the screen resolution of the viewer. I've placed my code on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DfKSE/)

Everything was good until I got to the education section and the footer. I don't know why it's behaving differently since I copied the code for education from the work info but somehow it is. It seems to have this big space at the top when viewing in JSFiddle and not when I view it in a browser. Also, when I make the browser window smaller, it stays in one place and the text from the work section overlaps it. I want everything to resize and move downwards if the window is made smaller, not just overlap each other. Here is the CSS for those sections but there is more on JSFiddle:

```
#contact {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:37%;
}

#education {
    width:115px;
    height:115px;
    background-color:#dfadec;
    margin-top:1160px;
    margin-bottom:70px;

}
#education p {
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-left:10px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-top:47px;
    font-weight:600;
}
#ed_desc {
    position:absolute;
    left:140px;
    top:1660px;
    width:450px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:18px;
}
```

And for the footer, it was in a table and whatever I did made it look proper on my screen but if I resize, it doesn't move. It just stays in one place so it gets cut off. I also feel like my code is a mess with all the padding and margins but maybe that's normal when using this many divs..?

If anyone can offer advice on how I can clean this up and make it more responsive yet be in this same layout, I'd really appreciate it. Here's the screenshot of what it's supposed to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDbsv.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first answer.

If I were you I would use [getskeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) , this is a

> A Beautiful Boilerplate for Responsive, Mobile-Friendly Development

So imagine you have 16 columns and put  each element the number of column based on the width you want them have.

In one container you want the sum of the columns of the elements to be 16. You have the class offset-by to make this happen.

So I would add this classes to your elements:

- header: container (this set the width to 100%, for different screen sizes)
- title: five columns offset-by-five
- nav: six columns

And the same with the next.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. Will this also work for desktop responsiveness or is it only mobile? I would like to achieve both.

Comment: This is for every screen size, desktop tablet/iPad and mobile